# Sort dict by key and retrieve value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Given `scores = { 0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}`

To get the output `[ "bob", "carl", "alex" ]`

I can do `print([ scores[key] for key in sorted(scores.keys()) ])`

Is this the best (most "pythonic") way? I was thinking I could use `scores.items()` in conjunction with `sorted(key=...)` to avoid the dictionary lookup, but not sure what that `key` parameter would be.

Comment: Dictionary lookup doesn't have any noticeable cost. Your solutions is perfectly Pythnoic but you may be able to make it more costly by changing the algorithms or maybe the data structure.

Comment: Yes, your solution is fine (the `.keys()` is unnecessary, though).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 good shout, thanks

Comment: I think you just have the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over `dict` will always use the keys, so you don't have to use the `.keys()` method.

Also, try [not to use](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) space after and before parenthesis.

```py
scores = {0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}
print([scores[key] for key in sorted(scores)])
```

For more functional approach, you can also use:

```py
scores = {0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}
print(list(map(scores.get, sorted(scores))))
```

But your solution is perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using `.items()`, the key argument is `key=lambda t: t[0]`, but in this case `key=lambda t: t` works the same (but breaks ties by the value).  `t` is used as key by default so you don't need to specify one:

```
scores = {0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}
print(sorted(scores.items()))
```

outputs:

```
[(0.0, 'bob'), (2.8, 'carl'), (5.2, 'alex')]
```

now to get a list of values you can "unzip" like this:

```
print(
    list(list(zip(*sorted(scores.items())))[1])
)
```

Comment: You don't need a `key` for sorted in this case.

Comment: I meant to say t[0] , but even then i don't really need a key

Comment: If you wanna go with sorting the `items` I think you should do `next(zip(*sorted(scores.items())))`.

Comment: The OP only asked for a list of values from the original dict, not a list of key/value tuples.

Comment: oh okay, will add that

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a generator object yielding the values of the dict,
cast them to a list and then print it.

`print(list(val for val in scores.values()))`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below the code content, it will be sort dict by key.

```
scores = { 0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}
for key, value in sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0], reverse=True):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

> 5.2: alex
>   2.8: carl
>   0.0: bob

Answer (score 0):

To sort dictionary by their keys and retrieve their values:

```
# This is your initial dictionary
scores = { 0.0: "bob", 5.2: "alex", 2.8: "carl"}

# This sorts your dictionary by it's keys as mentioned by x[0]
sorted_scores = {k:v for k, v in sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])}

# Now we are getting all the values in the sorted order and storing it in result
result = list(sorted_scores.values())

# Now, result will be:
['bob', 'carl', 'alex']

# Also sorted_scores will be:
{0.0: 'bob', 2.8: 'carl', 5.2: 'alex'}
```